# how to make the cards pull up and down depending on the space available,

Tags: html, css, position

Here's what needs to be done:[image]

That is, the blocks can be different heights, but there should be no empty spaces
[image]

I tried it with both flexbox and grid, but nothing works. please help. i even asked gpt, but he didn't understand me. i really hope they can help me here.

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

         .cards-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
            grid-auto-rows: min-content;
            grid-auto-flow: dense;
            gap: 16px;
            padding: 16px;
        }

        .card {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 16px;
            text-align: left;
            border-radius: 5px;
            height: fit-content;
        }


        .card h3 {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

    </style>
    <body>
      <div class="cards-container">

        {% for user in users %}
            <div class="card">
                <h3>{{ user.name }}</h3>
                <p>Email: {{ user.email }}</p>
                <p>Телефон: {{ user.phone }}</p>
                <p>Опыт работы: {{ user.experience }}</p>
                <p>Образование: {{ user.education }}</p>
                <p>Навыки: {{ user.skills }}</p>
                <p>Вакансия: {{ user.vacancy.name }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: What you are looking for is called **masonry layout** or **masonry-grid**